# Why doesn't the sibling selector work for contenteditable elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've put together this pen: https://codepen.io/NanoSpicer/pen/YzQgQVd

The idea is that using the sibling selector I want to style a certain element when the element before the one I want to style is focused.

It works great with input elements, but it fails miserably when using elements with `contenteditable` attribute:

```css
.container,
form {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

div[contenteditable="true"]::before {
  text-color: gray;
  opacity: 0.6;
  content: attr(placeholder);
}

div[contenteditable="true"],
input {
  /* remove system hightlighting*/
  outline-style: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  min-height: 40px;
  appearance: none;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: gray;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

div[contenteditable="true"]:focus,
input:focus {
  border-color: blue;
}

*:focus+* {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input placeholder="first" id="first" type="text">
  <input placeholder="second" id="second" type="password">
</form>
<div class="container">
  <div contenteditable="true" placeholder="first"></div>
  <div contenteditable="true" placeholder="second"></div>
</div>
```

**Note**: Tested on Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is very strange. Probably a bug.

This workaround is good for Firefox and Chrome on PC. Didn't test other browsers / platforms.

```
[contenteditable]:focus + * {
  border-color:green;
}
```

Comment: Both answeres figured it out: Add the attribute selector. Upvoted both but accepted this one because it was the first one to appear, but they are both good.

Answer (score 1):

Just like you did for in the beginning of your CSS, be more specific to indicate you want to react with the `contenteditable` attribute.

By default, `div` are not editable, so not `focusable`, so you have to be a bit more specific with this.

To make this work, you should edit the last CSS property to add the second selector line like I wrote here :

```
*:focus + *,
div[contenteditable="true"]:focus + div {
  border-color: red;
}
```

or if you want to make it more generic:

```
*:focus + *,
*[contenteditable="true"]:focus + * {
  border-color: red;
}
```